# Firebase service named 'auth' already registered

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5, angularfire2

Get  this Error in console while using firebase and angularfire2 in my app

```
 uncaught exception: auth: Firebase: Firebase service named 'auth' already registered (app/duplicate-service).
```

According to this answer
https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react/issues/15

I have check the code again but I am calling `firebase.initializeApp(...)`only one time in my `app.module.ts`.

Now i am stuck and don't know where to start? Thank you in advance for any small help.

Comment: if all else fails just backup your files and `firebase init` from firebase tools. That will re-write the rules and everything back to default though - but you could copy what you had back in. You might look at `firebase.json` and make sure it looks right (no duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below solution,

> I had included the latest versions of firebase.js and angularfire.js
>   from bower. I copied the code in the readme and removed the
>   firebase-app.js line because I assumed it's the same as firebase.js
>
> I just realized auth is already baked in to either firebase.js or
>   angularfire.js. Removing the firebase-auth.js line in your sample code
>   solved the issue.

**[Related Issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/11)**

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan finally got where was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am using both

```
import '@firebase/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

in my client.

So I actually have both in my **package.json**,

```
"@firebase/auth": "0.11.3",
"firebase": "5.9.3",
```

After I remove `@firebase/auth` from **package.json**, the error is gone.

Seems `firebase` package includes `@firebase/auth` already.